# How to allow line breaks when extracting text from pdf reader?

Tags: javascript

I refer to this code form [codepen](https://codepen.io/maximus-su/pen/GRqoZEb)

```
return textContent.then(function (text) {

return text.items.map(function (s) {
console.log(s)
return s.str;
  
}).join('');  });
```

I have tried using `console.log(s)` with the hope that I am able to get an indication of line breaks.

[image: Picture of the problem]

You can select any files which contain words in it. It would be helpful to provide a codepen demo which solves the line break issue. Your help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
countPromises.push(page.then(function (page) {
    var textContent = page.getTextContent();
    return textContent.then(function (text) {
        return text.items.map(function (s) {
            console.log(s);
            return s.str;
        }).join('');});
}));
```

working solution:

```
countPromises.push(page.then(function (page) {
    var textContent = page.getTextContent();
    return textContent.then(function (text) {
        return text.items.map(function (s) {
            console.log(s);
            return s.str;
        }).join('<p></p>');});
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To How to allow line breaks when extracting text from pdf reader?

```
<iframe id="input" src="your-file.pdf"></iframe>

<iframe id="processor" src="http://hubgit.github.com/2011/11/pdftotext/"></iframe>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var processor = document.getElementById("processor");
var output = document.getElementById("output");


window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
  if (event.source != processor.contentWindow) return;

  switch (event.data){
    case "ready":
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
      xhr.open('GET', input.getAttribute("src"), true);
      xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
      xhr.onload = function(event) {
        processor.contentWindow.postMessage(this.response, "*");
      };
      xhr.send();
    break;

    default:
      output.textContent = event.data.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
    break;
  }
}, true);
</script>
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.